# Session data change when refresh page in LAN using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session, cookies, iis-7, web-config

I have save user related data  in session like user_id.And All things Drive with User_Id like display data, insert data and all. In LAN multiple user login at a time. when they refresh page simultaneously. Session data over write automatically by user and data mixed or display incorrect. So  How can uniquely manage session data.

*i have try this in web.config but it's not working*

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" 
                cookieless="false" />
```

Please help me.

Comment: `Session` is unique as per user. Are you using the different tab of the same browser? Also put the code where you are setting the values in the `Session` values.

Comment: No, When access different user with different PC with different Browser

Comment: Thanks Sir, Can you help me. How can put the code when setting the value

Answer (score 1):

You can try property get and set for session store through the project. It will better coding manner.  Refer below code.

```
public class appSession
{
    public appSession()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

    public static int UserId
    {
        get
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"] == null)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                return (Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"]));
            }
        }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"] = value; }
    }
}
```

I have made static property so you can use it easily like below code.

```
appSession.UserId = objUsers.UserId;
```

Hope this method of accessing session will help you.